# multiple delimiters awk when one of the delimiters is 4 underscores (not one)

Tags: awk

```
PWD=sgy_comp.20170328_090951.20170328_090730.d_0327____20170325_002526.seiscat
```

I need to delimit on both of these `.` and `____`

If I try and use (this does not work) the normal syntax of `[.____]` then it treats the `____` as 4 delimiters (since it treats `____` the same as `_`)

Example:

```
basename $PWD
sgy_comp.20170328_090951.20170328_090730.d_0327____20170325_002526.seiscat

basename $PWD|awk -F[."____"] '{print $4}'
090951
```

I'm trying to get a return of `d_0327`.  I understand why it is not working the way that I would like, just looking for the right syntax to make it work.

Comment: are those underscores, or do they represent a space character?

Comment: sorry - all underscores are actually underscore (not back spaces)

Comment: also - not used PWD as my own variable, just showing what PWD contains

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[<set>]` matches *one* character (extended to *collating element* with some tools and in some circumstances) from the provided *`<set>`*.

`[.____]` specifically matches *one* character provided it's either `.` or `_`, or `_`, or `_` or `_`. Needless to say, `[.____]` is the same as `[._]`.

If you want to match either of two strings, you need the `|` alternation operator:

```
awk -F '\\.|____' '{print $4}'
```

With modern (and standard) `awk`s, you can also write it:

```
awk -F '\\.|_{4}' '{print $4}'
```

Also note that `[...]` needs quoting for the shell as `[...]` also happens to be a shell globbing operator. In your case, you only quoted the `____` part for the shell. That wasn't needed as `_` is not special to the shell. That means that with `-F[."____"]`, if there was a file called `-F.` or `-F_` in the current directory, the shell globbing would expand `-F[."____"]` to those before passing to `awk`. If not, `-F[.____]` would be passed to `awk` (though some shells would report an error instead about that glob with no match).

Comment: I tried both of these, but only get a warning:   awk: warning: escape sequence `\.' treated as plain `.'

Comment: @ced, Sorry, my bad, it should have been `\\.` or `[.]`. Edited now.